# Regular Expression to match first character and after a character

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

- `___abcd-metadata.json`

I am trying to do a regex to get `___` and everything after `-`. So far I have this Regex:

`(\-.*?\.json)`

To find the last part and (`___`) to find the first part, but I have not been able to figure how to combine both regexes to make this happen.

My desired result would be `___ -metadata.json = true`

Comment: my expected match should be ___-metadata.json true

Comment: @user1766952 Please [edit] the question so that it’s readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Comment: `___` is not even there in your input anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"(\-)(.*)"` is the pattern, which will give you 2 matches if the string contains them.

Answer (score -1):

Take your string and use `String.split('-')` to break it into parts.

EDIT

```
var parts =  ('_abcd-metadata.json').split('-'),
start = parts[0].substr(0,3),
rest = parts[1];
```

Comment: ```var parts =  ('_abcd-metadata.json').split('-'),
    start = parts[0].substr(0,3),
    rest = parts[1];```